# Chart.js different y axis depending on graph from select options

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, yaxis

I am trying to display different y axis based on the new set of json data that is passed through from the select options when they are clicked.

This is my code:

```
var chartOptions = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                display: true,
                autoSkip: true,
                maxTicksLimit: 25
            }
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: false,
                // Return an empty string to draw the tick line but hide the tick label
                // Return `null` or `undefined` to hide the tick line entirely
                userCallback: function (value, index, values) {


                    if (KpiName === "sales_growth_ytd") 
                    {
                        return value + '%';
                    }
                    else {

                        value = value.toString();
                        value = value.split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/);
                        // console.log($scope.selects);

                        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.selects.length; i++)
                        {

                              if($scope.selects[i].country_name === "Eire")
                            {
                                console.log($scope.selects[i].country_name);
                                return '€' + value;
                            }
                        }

                        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.selects.length; i++)
                        {

                            if($scope.selects[i].country_name === "UK")
                            {
                                console.log($scope.selects[i].country_name);
                                return '£' + value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    responsive: true,
    options: {
        legend: {
            labels: {
                // This more specific font property overrides the global property
                fontSize: 15,
                fontStyle: 'bold',
            },
            animation: {
                duration: 1 // general animation time
            },
            hover: {
                animationDuration: 0 // duration of animations when hovering an item
            },
            responsiveAnimationDuration: 0, // animation duration after a resize
            elements: {
                line: {
                    tension: 0 // disables bezier curves
                }
            },
        }
    }
};
```

Based on the country that is pulled through on the select options, i.e UK or EIRE, I would like to display the value with £ or € on the Y axis.

How would i do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `userCallback` runs for each tick. In your code you return a value, when any value's country_name in `$scope.selects` matches 'Eire' or 'UK'.. Is that what you want?

I dont know enough about your data, but if the `country_name` is dependant on the dataset and not each data point, you could create a currency prefix variable outside of the userCallback and add it onto the tick values:

```
// Load dataset
// set currency prefix based on the data
...
userCallback: function (value, index, values) {
    if (KpiName === "sales_growth_ytd") 
    {
        return value + '%';
    }
    else {
        return currency_prefix + value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes i have now resolved the issue, the code above is set in a function with changes based on a get request, and i am now pulling through the relevant country names and Ids from the functions params to set in the If statement when the country is Eire or UK :). Thanks for your help